# Binary file won't run

Tags: linux

So I'm trying to install a custom Linux binary file, but when I try to run the app, it says `No such file or directory`. I'm trying to find where the problem is. Here are some tests I ran:

./app.cgi:

```
-bash: ./app.cgi: No such file or directory
```

gdb app.cgi:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see: <http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
"app.cgi": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

uname -a:

```
Linux srv1 3.2.61-grsec-modsign #1 SMP Tue Aug 12 09:58:26 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

file app.cgi:

```
app.cgi: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

Comment: You're missing the 32bit libraries required to run the 32bit executable.

Comment: Shouldn't a 64bits Linux be able to run 32bits binaries natively? How do I find out which packages I'm missing exactly? And can I install those without root access (it's a shared system).

Comment: 32bit Linux can't run 32bit binaries without the required 32bit libraries either. You can use `ldd` to see which libraries it's missing. I strongly suggest you build from source or get a 64bit version for your specific distro release instead